# Problem while accessing a java file on ubuntu

Tags: permissions, java

So basically i have installed ubuntu bash from microsoft store in windows 10.I have installed java on ubuntu (the native os is windows 10).javac is working perfactly even it displays the version of java which i have installed(javac 9.0.4).The file name is HelloWorld.java.[The java version and rest of the problem is displayed in the this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CupzJ.png)

The code is simple hello world program

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}

}
```

Even when i try to open the file with pico it displays the same error.  **[ Error reading HelloWorld.java: Permission denied ]**

**Solution: chmod u+r filename**
But one problem still remains is how to give this permission automatically to all the files which will be copied from windows to ubuntu directory?

Comment: Add the output of `ls -l HelloWorld.java`

Comment: The output of ls -l HelloWorld.java is  ---------- 1 aditya aditya 188 Mar 17 23:26 HelloWorld.java.It seems like it does not have any permission. @user000001

Comment: it means you have no permissions. Try `chmod u+r HelloWolrd.java`, but I just noticed that it's on windows, no idea how you can fix permissions there, sorry..

Comment: I tried `chmod u+r HelloWolrd.java` and it worked thanks mate.But Every file that i created on windows copied in ubuntu directory(C:\Users\aditya\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\aditya) should be modified with explicit permission to read how to avoid this problem?How to give it permission for reading automatically for the copied file @user000001?

Answer (score 0):

To change permissions of all the .java files in the Ubuntu directory:

1. Change directories with `cd` to the Ubuntu directory.
2. Run this command:

   ```
   chmod u+rw *.java
   ```